# Steam not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS i386

Tags: steam

Steam doesn't seem to work on my Ubuntu 14.04

I installed steam using `sudo apt-get install steam`
and open it using `steam`

Here's the log:

```
ryzokuken@ubuntu:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-02-16 01:37:02] Startup - updater built Nov 25 2013 18:07:05
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-02-16 01:37:03] Checking for update on startup
[2016-02-16 01:37:03] Checking for available update...
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Download failed: http error 0
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.b9c015520018655499338cfc2c3a3159e28bbe14 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.c74a3a9beb77a280cfd8761b901a80ed0f6a3173 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.505590f6014431a95a9750073e466372f3e98d88 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.20ccff954777943069dd2c57576216f5f1db7389 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.843f5376c132f306d1b21dc564b3fe2057104e24 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.1784c1309339550c71fd577c7db309892a675074 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.a4dc0ed3ca1a4d603fb6913907df318eb957273d missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.6b98785251045457e56ce493e4974efc336c1912 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file resources_all.zip.d4f565b83152b9018d059896aaf8525cdbdb5964 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file strings_en_all.zip.9dc3fdb2c7b61fc8754b4635077f35e3a3611e94 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file strings_all.zip.6312352791737e2e929a9eb23ab39fb078be39ae missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file remoteui_all.zip.ba22fb168ed139d9979cdd1cefbd911e3ed3529c missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file public_all.zip.903c1663eeeea9339119d1dd349be100198a0582 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.506ba970ef5abb73af12c47455906cf793827131 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.ebcdfc2a165395d488ef60caf3c3077f3901e777 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.c6fb0b1fa5ce3f1576e5d426db4f652913eb1794 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.97633922c0d11a1cdd9a059924187deff71bddd6 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.09a87cc6ade2e51d6d2bd73d51368ab20abedbd5 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.b8914fd00cec2e3adea3f015777a740b431baa56 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.58ed79e82eff221812f19312c287218e60573807 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.89ec28c977e24ebab035610b0f6d119bf3e5ff0d missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.8745630cc886d5834e6228ad60aea0d095eaaea5 missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.c29ba2cbbfa2ca89bd12b96bd7bd31c07c1314ec missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.bbf1802326f84fbf05f4b8983b7ea6d091aad63c missing or incorrect size
[2016-02-16 01:41:18] Downloading update (0 of 307,302 KB)...
[2016-02-16 01:45:33] Error: Download of package (tenfoot_misc_all) failed after 0 bytes (0).
```

I have had similar problems in all my earlier installations. However, I expected better results this time because:

1. I earlier installed amd64 although my computer is 32-bit
2. I had a stupid or outdated video drivers (this time, I just used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`)

Comment: make sure that new version of xfonts are installed using the following in terminal, `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi`

Comment: i already installed xfonts-100dpi and xfonts-75dpi

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all graphics drivers using,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Uninstall steam using,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam
```

And install latest version of xfonts using `sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi`.

After Reboot the system. Install *steam* and *drivers*.

Probably, it will solve this.

**EDIT 1:**

May be there is a problem in your os arch. Try the following,

Install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386, using `# aptitude install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386` in terminal.

This may fix it.

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Here are my [logs](http://pastebin.com/gMaGzdcr)

Comment: @Ryzokuken, try edit 1 in my answer.

Comment: @A J: # makes it a comment. Do i skip the `#` ? Also, do i need to `sudo apt-get install aptitude` or do i `sudo apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386`

Comment: @Ryzokuken, `#` - means to be a root, login as a root and do `aptitude install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386`, if you not installed `aptitude`, install it by using `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Comment: A J: 

`root@ubuntu:/home/ryzokuken# aptitude install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
No candidate version found for libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
No candidate version found for libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.`

Comment: @Ryzokuken, which OS version you are using ? 64b or 32b ?

Comment: 32 bit (I specified i386)